# Using reflection to set an interface member

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, propertyinfo

I'm having trouble setting the value of a property in a class when the property type is and interface using PropertyInfo.SetValue.
This code is for unit testing which I'd like to use to fake out the IDbSets in my Entity.

```
public static void AddFakeDbSets<T>(this Mock<T> obj) where T : class
{
    var iDbSets = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => 
        p.PropertyType.IsGenericType == true &&
        p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name.StartsWith("IDbSet"));

    Type baseType = typeof(FakeDbSet<>);

    foreach (var iDbSet in iDbSets)
    {
        if (iDbSet.GetValue(obj.Object) == null)
        {
            var genericType = baseType.MakeGenericType(iDbSet.PropertyType);
            var concreteObject = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
            iDbSet.SetValue(obj.Object, concreteObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically it crashes at iDbSet.SetValue() with the following error:

> Object of type
>   'lnEcommAPI.Tests.FakeDbSet`1[System.Data.Entity.IDbSet`1[LNWebServicesRepository.WhatsNew]]'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet`1[LNWebServicesRepository.WhatsNew]'.

Comment: For future readers: Answer fixes the crash, but Moq still gets in the way of assigning the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess: replace

```
var genericType = baseType.MakeGenericType(iDbSet.PropertyType);
```

by

```
var genericType = baseType.MakeGenericType(iDbSet.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
```

The problem is that `iDbSet.PropertyType` is equal to `IDbSet<XXX>`.
Thus, `typeof(FakeDbSet<>).MakeGenericType(iDbSet.PropertyType)` creates a `FakeDbSet<IDbSet<XXX>>`, while you're expecting a `FakeDbSet<XXX>`

Comment: Excellent catch, it no longer crashes but the property does not get set either. Kind of a head-scratcher, I was thinking it had something to do with Moq, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: In this case, it's not the same problem !

Comment: Your property setter may be empty for instance... try to inspect iDbSet.GetGetMethod().GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray().Length ... if it's less than 4 bytes long, then your setter does nothing :)

Comment: Cool trick; GetMethodBody is 11 bytes and SetMethodBody is 8.

Comment: Additionally the following code does not set the property either: `var setter = iDbSet.GetSetMethod();
var result = setter.Invoke(obj.Object, new [] { concreteObject });`

Comment: 8 & 11 is very likely to be a traditional automatic get/set property with a field ... could you copy/paste iDbSet.GetSetMethod().GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray() bytes here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61572/discussion-between-olivier-and-jonathan-demarks).